# Testing Vuex reducer/mutation in Vue3/Vue-test-utils

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vuejs3, vuex

I am in the process of migrating to Vue3, so please excuse me for not just using Pinia. I have a reducer like this:

```
export const mutations: MutationTree<UiState> = {
  SET_LOADING: (state, loading) => {
    Object.assign(state, loading); // before Vue3 this was Vue.set(...) for reactivity
  },
};
```

and a test like this

```
it('should set consultationLoading', () => {
  const state = uiState();
  const loading = true;
  const { SET_LOADING } = mutations;
  SET_LOADING(state, loading);
  expect(state.loading).toBe(loading);
});
```

Since I cannot use Vue.set() (from `import Vue from 'vue';`) anymore, I just went with Object.assign as recommended in another post. But the state is not updating in the test.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The purpose of `Vue.set` is to trigger an update where it won't normally work by assignment due to the limitations of Vue 2, this is no longer a problem in Vue 3.

This is JavaScript and not reactivity problem. Currently it's `Object.assign(obj, bool)` which does nothing.

Should be:

```
Object.assign(state, { loading: true })
```

Which is the same as:

```
state.loading = true
```

Comment: Ah yes, normally I just use spread operator instead of Object.assign, I missed the wrong param. Thank you